# ios code to calcuate the height of label using boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context return a value which is 40 pixels more than it should

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code which calculate the height of my label depends on the text I set the label to. But what I find out is it is always 40 pixels more than it should (I trial and error to find that value 40). Does anyone have the same problem? If yes, what is the possible solution?

```
    NSDictionary *stringAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myLabel.font
                                                              forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
     // width is the width of the label
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(width, NSUIntegerMax);
    CGSize expectedLabelSize =
    [text boundingRectWithSize:size
                        options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                     attributes:stringAttributes
                        context:nil].size;

// expectedLabelSize.height is 40 pixel than it should.
// If I manually - 40 from the value expected
```

Thank you.

Comment: Is it 40 more than expected for any string? What do you expect (and why)? What is the font, width, and text you are testing with?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the other way of calculating the height?

First you set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property of your label.

Then simply call `intrinsicContentSize` of your label to get its intrinsic size, then get the height.

It is simpler for me so I use it all the time.